# Instantiating - what does it do?

Tags: ios

As a self taught, or rather SO taught, programmer I have wondered for a while what actually happens when you set a variable or a let.  Today I was given help, very kindly by @Cocoadelica, in setting up a pattern for onboarding users.  We settled on this solution:

**AppDelegate.swift**

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

    let isOnboarded:Bool = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().boolForKey("Onboarded")

    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    // instantiate your desired ViewController
    let dashboardViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("DashboardVC") as! UIViewController
    let onboardingViewControllerOne = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("OnboardingVCOne") as! UIViewController

    let window = self.window

    if (isOnboarded) {
            window!.rootViewController = dashboardViewController

        }else{
            window!.rootViewController = onboardingViewControllerOne
    }

    return true
}
```

But I notice that it instantiates two viewControllers, even though the logic will only need one.  I see this quite often. We instantiate variables that will never be used, rather than when they are needed. Why do we do this?
Does it not have an impact on performance, or is it so small that we do it regardless because humans are humans and it makes the code a bit more clear perhaps?

Comment: Just to let you know: there is also a Pattern called lazy initialization. Instead of creating all objects at once one try to delay the initialization until the object is really needed. [link](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_initialization)

Comment: @Duc I noticed that you can't do lazy let, only lazy var.  Why? And I have gotten the impression that let's are less costly than var's,  So what is better let's or lazy var's ? Perhaps this is a silly question/comment..

Comment: "I noticed that you can't do lazy let, only lazy var" It is a known and regrettable limitation of Swift, which I expect will eventually be overcome. In the meantime it is not difficult to implement it yourself, as I demonstrate in my book: http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/ch03.html#EXlazy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> we do it regardless because humans are humans and it makes the code a bit more clear perhaps?

Exactly so, but now let's talk about the "cost". An instance of a view controller is, of itself, a lightweight object. And the one that is not retained by assigning it to `rootViewController` will be destroyed automatically when this method returns, a fraction of a millisecond later.

So yes, it is a waste of an instance, but the waste is tiny and probably not worth worrying about in this situation.

Still, it isn't the best style in the world, in my view; I agree with your original suspicion that we should not instantiate at all if we don't have to. And there can be situations where instantiation is expensive! So I personally would rewrite like this, and I suspect you would too:

```
let window = self.window
if (isOnboarded) {
    let dashboardViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("DashboardVC") as! UIViewController
    window!.rootViewController = dashboardViewController
 } else {
    let onboardingViewControllerOne = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("OnboardingVCOne") as! UIViewController
    window!.rootViewController = onboardingViewControllerOne
}
```

By the way, there is a lot of other stupid stuff in that code snippet, so I wouldn't take it as much of a model for anything if I were you.  For example, the line `let window = self.window` does nothing useful and can be omitted entirely. And there is no need for the explicit `Bool` declaration; Swift knows that `boolForKey` yields a Bool.